# How to pass JSON response in Go BeeGo framework?

Tags: json, rest, go, beego

I'm building microservices app with go and beego. I'm trying to pass JSON response from service A to service B as following:

```
func (u *ServiceController) GetAll() {
    req := httplib.Get("http://localhost/api/1/services")
    str, err := req.String()
    // str = {"id":1, "name":"some service"}
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    u.Data["json"] = str
    u.ServeJSON()
}
```

However, when I send the response I actually double json encoding:

```
"{\"id\":\"1\",\"name\":\"some service\"}"
```

Finally, this is the solution I came up with:

```
func (u *ServiceController) GetAll() {
    req := httplib.Get("http://localhost/api/1/services")
    str, err := req.String()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    strToByte := []byte(str)
    u.Ctx.Output.Header("Content-Type", "application/json")
    u.Ctx.Output.Body(strToByte)
}
```

Comment: https://beego.me/docs/mvc/controller/jsonxml.md

Comment: I want to parse the json dynamically.

Comment: As stated in the link `ServeJSON` "JSONifies" what you set as the value of `Data["json"]`, that means that a string gets turned into valid json string, regardless of the content of the string, that's why its escaped. `ServeJSON` is not meant to be used with strings containing json.

Comment: If you want to send strings containing valid json you can use `u.Ctx.Output.Body(bytes []byte)`, use `[]byte(str)` to convert your string into bytes. You'll need to also set the HTTP header Content-Type, which you can do like this: `u.Ctx.Output.Header("Content-Type", "application/json")`.

Comment: In JS I would parse to JSON to JS object beforehand, so what should I do in go?

Comment: `ServeJSON` does that for you, so it expects a value that can be turned into json (e.g. a struct that has exported fields and the proper field tags), just like in the example where they pass `mystruct`, that value gets turned into a json object.

Comment: @mkopriva tnx! I updated your solution in my question. You can post the second solution with `mystruct` here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
func (u *ServiceController) GetAll() {
    req := httplib.Get("http://localhost/api/1/services")
    str, err := req.Bytes()
    // str = {"id":1, "name":"some service"}
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    u.Ctx.Output.Header("Content-Type", "text/plain;charset=UTF-8")
    u.Ctx.ResponseWriter.Write(str)
}
```

If you call `req.String()`, it will encode the `"` in the json string. I suggest you use `[]byte` to handle data usually.